# Subview constraints programmatically

Tags: ios, constraints

I want to do constraints for the email field programmatically. But its not working.

Image Description: 
There is an TopView. In that, the white box is the `TopInnerView`. Finally, if i add `EmailTextField` in that `TopInnerView`. It shows an error.

This is my code:

```
//MainView
    MainView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    MainView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [MainView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
     [self.view addSubview:MainView];

//TopView
TopView = [[UIView alloc]init];
TopView.backgroundColor = [UIColor groupTableViewBackgroundColor];
[MainView addSubview:TopView];
[TopView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

//TopInnerView
TopInnerView = [[UIView alloc]init];
TopInnerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[TopView addSubview:TopInnerView];
[TopInnerView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

//EmailTextField
EmailTextField = [[UITextField alloc]init];
//WithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 270, 40)];
EmailTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
[TopInnerView addSubview:EmailTextField];
id views = @{
                     @"TopView": TopView,
                     @"TopInnerView": TopInnerView,
                     @"CenterView":CenterView,
                     @"BottomView": BottomView,
                     @"EmailTextField":EmailTextField
                     };

// TopView constraints
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[TopView(320)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:TopView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]];
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:TopView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0 constant:110]];
//[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:TopView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]];
NSLayoutConstraint *TopViewHeightConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:TopView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight multiplier:1.0 constant:170.0];
[self.view addConstraint:TopViewHeightConstraint];


// TopInnerView constraints
[TopView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-20-[TopInnerView]-20-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
[TopView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[TopInnerView(80)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:TopInnerView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:TopView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0 constant:0]];
[TopView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:TopInnerView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:TopView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]];
//[TopView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:TopInnerView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:TopView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]];

//EmailTextField Constriants
//[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[EmailTextField(270)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
//Leading Constriant
NSLayoutConstraint *Leading = [NSLayoutConstraint
                                constraintWithItem:EmailTextField
                                attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                toItem:self.view
                                attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                multiplier:1.0
                                constant:10.0];

//Trailing Constriant
    NSLayoutConstraint *Trailing = [NSLayoutConstraint
                                   constraintWithItem:EmailTextField
                                   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                   relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                   toItem:self.view
                                   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                   multiplier:1.0
                                   constant:0.0];

    [self.view addConstraint:Leading];
    [self.view addConstraint:Trailing];

[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:EmailTextField attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:TopInnerView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0 constant:0]];
NSLayoutConstraint *EmailTextFieldHeightConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:EmailTextField attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight multiplier:1.0 constant:40.0];
[self.view addConstraint:EmailTextFieldHeightConstraint];
```

Comment: Please add your error.

Answer (score 0):

To be sure, programmatic constraints can be a delicate thing to work with and they can make you crazy. That being said, I am seeing a few things going on here that would make me nervous if this were my design.

First, you are creating each view and adding each one as a subview to the view you just created (which is not necessarily wrong).  Then, you are relating each view constraint to it is corresponding parent view- except with the `EmailTextField` where you are relating the first two constraints to `self.view`.

Next, your `Leading` constraint is using the `NSLayoutAttributeTrailing` attribute; I'm betting this was a typo and should be `NSLayoutAttributeLeading`. Without seeing your error I can not be sure, but I'm betting you need to change your first two relations for `EmailTextView` to something like this:

```
//EmailTextView
[TopInnerView addSubview:EmailTextField];
NSLayoutConstraint *Leading = [NSLayoutConstraint
                                constraintWithItem:EmailTextField
                                attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                toItem:TopInnerView
                                attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                multiplier:1.0
                                constant:10.0];

//Trailing Constraint
    NSLayoutConstraint *Trailing = [NSLayoutConstraint
                                   constraintWithItem:EmailTextField
                                   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                   relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                   toItem:TopInnerView
                                   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                   multiplier:1.0
                                   constant:0.0];
```

Both of these are then being added as constraints to `self.view` which would be consistent considering how you had these constraints defined.  However, you finally define two more constraints between the `EmailTextField` and `InnerTopView` and add those constraints to `self.view` which is not consistent with how you are doing it previously. Using your existing design, I would *try* this:

```
[TopInnerView addConstraint:Leading];
[TopInnerView addConstraint:Trailing];
```

Your last two constraints could benefit from receiving this same consistency treatment; I will leave that up to you as an exercise.

Overall, I am betting the UI is probably just choking on all of the embedded constraints.  If these adjustments don't help I would recommend walking your code back to where you first defined the `EmailTextField` object. Then work over each constraint one by one to make sure you are defining each one consistently.  Finally, add each one to the UI hierarchy one at a time, making sure you are being consistent in your approach there as well.  Eventually you will find the constraint that is causing your problem.

Comment: For Example,If i want to add a button in a subview means.what are all the constriants i have to look for?